# How to tell form_with in conjunction with STI classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class that I'm using STI with to provide unique, per-type logics.  I do *not* want to create forms and controllers for each unique type, I want to leverage inheritance and have a single controller using the superclass, `Package`, with the subclasses not even being referenced (at this stage).

The new 'form_with' helper handles 99% of cases for me, but in this case the below code doesn't work.  It throws an error because @package is a subclass of the core Package class, and that subclass doesn't have routing information.  I need it to map the Package class and associated controllers instead.

```
<%= form_with(model: [@show, @package], local: true) do |form| %>
  # Form Data Here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= form_with(@package.becomes[Package]) do |form| %>
  # Form Data Here
<% end %>
```

Answer (score -1):

This solution seems a little hackey, but it's the best I've been able to come up with.  I suspect that it may *be* the best, absent form_with having some specific code to handle / recognize STI that I couldn't find documentation for.

```
<%= form_with(url: show_packages_path(@show,@package),scope: 'package' ,model: [@show, @package], local: true) do |form| %>
  # Form data Here
<% end %>
```

By using the `show_packages_path` helper, I'm able to forcibly scope the route to a specific route.  It's not as clean and flexible, but the extra code is there specifically to handle STI.  The same for the scope key, which re-scopes the form so it doesn't try to nest all the params under the subclass name instead of the superclass name.